# python regular expression to parse div tags

Tags: python, regex

a question about python regular expression.

I would like to match a div block like

```
<div class="leftTail"><ul class="hotnews">any news stuff</ul></div>
```

I was thinking a pattern like

```
p = re.compile(r'<div\s+class=\"leftTail\">[^(div)]+</div>')
```

but it seems not working properly

another pattern

```
p = re.compile(r'<div\s+class=\"leftTail\">[\W|\w]+</div>')
```

i got much more than i think, it gets all the stuff until the last  tag in the file.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `[^(div)]` matches any character except 5 listed in brackets. Thus this won't work if any of them could occur in div content. `\W` is an opposite for `\w`, so `[\W|\w]` is meaningless. The simplest way is to use non-greedy regexps like `.+?`. Consider using some real HTML parser if this is not the only task you are going to do with it.

Comment: tried .+? , seemed no luck... Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You might want to consider graduating to an actual HTML parser.  I suggest you give [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) a try.  There are many crazy ways for HTML to be formatted, and the regular expressions may not work correctly all the time, even if you write them correctly.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
p = re.compile(r'<div\s+class=\"leftTail\">.*?</div>')
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML or HTML. You'll never be able to get it to work correctly for nested divs.

Comment: Actually, you can, but it's a complete PITA and you're far better off to just use a proper X/HTML parser.

Comment: "Real" regular expressions can't deal with nesting. That's what separates regular languages from context free languages. Most regex implementations are more powerful than strictly regular, but most still aren't powerful enough to deal with nesting.